# XPATH expression to skip lines with attributes

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, nodes

I've got an XML with some nested nodes, say something like:

```
<root>
    <inner1>
        <foo resource_id="{123}">Line1</foo>
        <bar>Line2</bar>
    </inner1>
    <inner2>
        <inner3>
            <foo>Line3</foo>
            <bar resource_id="{456}">Line4</bar>
        </inner3>
    </inner2>
</root>
```

The lines with attribute `resource_id` can appear at any level in the XML file. I need to get an xpath that gives me the exact same file contents, but without the lines/nodes containing `resource_id` attribute. So the ideal output would be:

```
<root>
    <inner1>
        <bar>Line2</bar>
    </inner1>
    <inner2>
        <inner3>
            <foo>Line3</foo>
        </inner3>
    </inner2>
</root>
```

I've tried several xpath commands, but without success yet :/
I don't understand why this xpath:

`//*[@resource_id]`

Properly selects the nodes with the aforementioned attribute, but the command:

`//*[not(@resource_id)]`

selects all the nodes, even the ones with `resource_id` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath selects nodes in an existing tree so with e.g. `//*[not(@resource_id)]` you will get a node-set or sequence of nodes not having a `resource_id` attribute, but within the existing tree, meaning you select any ancestor of the elements with `resource_id` attribute and of course their children/descendants don't change, they continue to contain the elements with resource_id attribute.

That means that XPath alone is not powerful enough to give you the wanted result where you want a new tree with elements with `resource_id` attribute filtered out, you can use XSLT or XQuery for that e.g.

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@resource_id]"/>
```

in XSLT 3 will suffice to remove any elements with a `resource_id` attribute.